Disable doesn't work with element.created_by._id !== user_id
<button mat-icon-button aria-label="Edit" class="btn-edit"
         matTooltip="{{ 'Tooltip.Edit' | translate }}"
         [routerLink]="element?.status != announcementEnum.approved ? 
                            ['edit', element?._id] : 
                            null"
         [disabled]="(element.created_by._id !== user_id) &&
                     (element?.status == announcementEnum.approved)">
         <mat-icon svgIcon="icon-edit"></mat-icon>

I try this but still not work
[disabled]="((element.created_by._id !== user_id) && 
            (element?.status == announcementEnum.approved)) ? true:false"


You might need to inspect if the values are there for user_id. Also, you can try using !=  instead of !==.

The correct it's the first code. Use in .html {{element.status}}{{element.created_by._id}} {{user_id}}{{announcementEnum.approved}} inside the button to see the values
